# Treat Warnings as Errors in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, logging

How can I make the output of warnings in my reactjs project appear as errors? Something like using the `-Werror` flag in a gcc or cc compiler.

I want a behaviour such that instead of the logger logging

> Compiled with warnings.
>
> Some warnings here

rather log

> Compiled with errors.
>
> Some warnings here treated as errors

Or alternatively, not even compile until the warnings are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

"--max-warnings can serve this purpose: --max-warnings=0 means that any warnings cause eslint to report an error."

in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0",
  },
```

source:
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2309#issuecomment-219828044

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use Linting tools like ESLint allow you to discover problems with your JavaScript code without executing it. It has a plugin for react ESLint-plugin-React.

You can Enable the rules that you would like to use like this and make warning appear as an error.

```
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",
  "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
}
```

Or use all rules.

Check out [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-eslint-webpack-babel/) blog post for setup details.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion but unfortunately it did not help. I still get the warnings and they are still treated as warnings.